# Desativar case sensitive somente em uma comparação

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber, se existe uma forma de **"desativar" o case sensitive** em uma determinada comparação.

Exemplo:

```
var_dump('SQL'=='SQL'); # bool(true)

var_dump('SQL'=='sQL'); # bool(false)
```

---

Sei que existem formas de resolver, uma delas com `strtoupper()` ou `strtolower()`, mas **gostaria de saber especificadamente se tem como desativar** diretamente em uma comparação.

Comment: Também tem a função `strcasecmp` : `var_dump(strcasecmp('SQL', 'sQL'))`, mas não sei se é isso que esperava ver

Comment: Resolve! É comparativo entre 2 strings então serve perfeitamente!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diretamente não, mas pode ser utilizado uma função que realize a comparação insensitive, como a `strcasecmp`. Como já falou, você também pode manipular as `strings` para fazer a manipulação, utilizando `strtoupper` e `strolower`.

Você pode utilizar a função `strcasecmp` da seguinte forma:

```
if (strcasecmp("sQl", "SQL") == 0) {
    echo 'São iguais';
}
```

Quando o retorno da função é `0` é porque a duas `strings` são iguais. Quando a primeira `string` for menor que a segunda, o retorno será < 0. E quando a segunda `string` for menor que a primeira, o retorno será > 0. Você pode ver mais sobre a função na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strcasecmp.php) do PHP.

Comment: Só atentar para o fato de strings acentuadas não retornarem o resultado esperado. https://ideone.com/oktpEn

Answer (score 0):

A resposta curta é **não**

Mas como falou, pode passar os dois valores para strtoupper ou strolower e fazer a comparação, ou caso queira usar regex pode passar o modificador /i também.